# Android Studio 3.0.1 Shows Emulator: Process finished with exit code 1

Tags: android, android-studio, android-activity, android-emulator

I'm new to Linux. Recently I installed Android Studio 3.0.1. When I try to
create new AVD that time it shows me this error. Please, someone, help me to fix it.

> 7:02 PM   Emulator: emulator: ERROR: Unknown AVD name
>   [New_Device_API_26], use -list-avds to see valid list.
>
> 7:02 PM   Emulator: Process finished with exit code 1
>
> 7:10 PM   Emulator: emulator: ERROR: Unknown AVD name
>   [New_Device_API_26], use -list-avds to see valid list.
>
> 7:10 PM   Emulator: Process finished with exit code 1
>
> 7:10 PM   Emulator: emulator: ERROR: Unknown AVD name
>   [New_Device_API_26], use -list-avds to see valid list.
>
> 7:10 PM Emulator: Process finished with exit code 1

[image]

Comment: possible duplicate of https://stackoverflow.com/a/47739865/9130109

Comment: You can follow the commit here: [https://stackoverflow.com/a/50849307/3212311](https://stackoverflow.com/a/50849307/3212311)

Answer (score 13):

**I had this problem solved this way**

1.set place save AVD to environment

```
$ sudo nano /etc/environment 
$ ANDROID_AVD_HOME=/root/.android/avd
```

2.set place emulator in sdk to bash profile

```
$ sudo nano /etc/bash.bashrc
$ export ANDROID_HOME=${HOME}/Android/Sdk
$ export PATH=${PATH}:${ANDROID_HOME}/emulator
```

now reset studio and run emulator
if you see this error when start emulator

*libGL error: unable to load driver: i965_dri.so*

*AVD Emulator: Process finished with exit code -1*

do it this work

```
$ cd ~/Android/Sdk/emulator/lib64/libstdc++
$ mv libstdc++.so.6 libstdc++.so.6.bak
$ ln -s /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libstdc++.so.6 libstdc++.so.6
```

Comment: Omg, I was stuck on this problem all day and this finally worked for me. Thank you so much!!!

Answer (score 0):

I think you should open terminal in android studio
and then enter emulator -list-avds
It will tell you every virtual device created
if the list is empty then create a new virtual device
else press emulator @YOUR_AVD_NAME
and avd will start

Answer (score 0):

To avoid any type of errors, I launch the AVD directly from the terminal with this command:

```
/<path to sdk location>/tools/emulator -avd <AVD name> -use-system-libs
```

Comment: Thanks that actually helped. I still need to find out why this happens but at least it runs now.

Answer (score 0):

For windows users, see the ANDROID_SDK_HOME path,then check the ANDROID_SDK_HOME/avd/,is there that Emulator(you just created) existed?If there's not existed,then copy the emulator.avd and emulator.ini files in ANDROID_SDK_HOME/.android/avd/ to ANDROID_SDK_HOME/avd/, finally it did worked!