# How to fix this error in android studio emulator?

Tags: android, android-studio

I am currently using android studio 3.4 version.emmulator is not working properly.there is no defect in the code.

I tried a different version of the emulator but it not working properly.

it showing the same error to the emulator.

I am using ubantu 17.04 version

> 9:08 AM    Emulator: emulator: ERROR: Unknown AVD name [Nexus_S_API_28], use -list-avds to see valid list.
>
> 9:08 AM    Emulator: Process finished with exit code 1
>
> 8:59 AM    Gradle build finished in 3 s 928 ms
>
> 9:08 AM    Emulator: emulator: ERROR: Unknown AVD name [Nexus_S_API_28], use -list-avds to see valid list.
>
> 9:08 AM    Emulator: Process finished with exit code 1

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48747577/android-studio-3-0-1-shows-emulator-process-finished-with-exit-code-1

Answer (score 0):

Try creating a new Android Virtual Device and switch to that new device.

Go to Tools > AVD manager.

Click Create Virtual Device.

Choose this new AVD when running.

Comment: i tried to create new vertual device but it showing same error .

Comment: @SaurabhChopade
What names show up when you use -list-avds?

Comment: where to use  this -list-avds.   my avd name is  Nexus_S_API_28. i have changes avd name but it showing same error. Erroris showing like this .>>>                                                                                                                                       Emulator: emulator: ERROR: Unknown AVD name [Nexus_S_API_28], use -list-avds to see valid list.

Comment: @SaurabhChopade in the command prompt.

There's a number of things that could be wrong here and there's not enough info to know which it is.

I suggest deleting the avds that you set up and then recreating 1 by following the steps in the android studio user guide

https://developer.android.com/studio/run/managing-avds

Answer (score 0):

Try creating a new Android Virtual Device and delete old ones.

Go to Tools > AVD manager.

Click Create Virtual Device.

Choose option create new AVD and while selecting the System image please select Google Play image Platform.
select device Pixel (5.0) and then google image.

Answer (score 0):

Try this :

Go to Tools > Android > Uncheck Enable ADB Integration

then,

Tools > Android > Check Enable ADB Integration