# Emulator : Process finished with exit code 1/2

Tags: android, android-studio, android-emulator, android-virtual-device

My Virtual Device is a phone called Nexus 5 with the system Nougat
API 25
Android 7.1.1 (Google APIs)
How do I solve this problem in Android Studio?

Comment: An exit code <> 0 simply means that there is an error. The reasons for this may be too broad. Please add at least the stdout / stderr output (like here https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47739777/android-studio-avd-emulator-process-finished-with-exit-code-1).

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Android Studio AVD - Emulator: Process finished with exit code 1](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47739777/android-studio-avd-emulator-process-finished-with-exit-code-1)