# Android Studio: The emulator keeps crashing after sometime

Tags: android-emulator

Every time I run the emulator it runs normally at the beginning but after a couple of minutes it crashes and it's giving me this error:

```
emulator process finished with exit code 1073740791 (0xC0000409)
```

I am using windows 10 home edition. virtualization is enabled in bios. I don't have any other virtualization software installed (like virtual box).

any idea why this is happening?

Comment: @Mr.AF ??? not the same error, not even the same OS

Comment: I should add that for me the emulator never even completes booting. It crashes 2 or 3 seconds after starting

Comment: @Tim you are right .

Comment: maybe check logcat? `adb -e logcat`

Comment: If your emulator used to work, maybe the cache is messed up? Or user data? There are flags to disable/reset the emulator when starting it such as `emulator @EmulatorName -no-cache` or `-wipe-data`. Also if you don't have enough time to attach `logcat` you could specify an out file with `-logcat-output ./myLog.log`

Comment: @Elias actually this is the fist time trying to run an emulator on this PC

Comment: @Time and the logcat output?

Comment: @Tim: Please try 2 things. 1) set your graphics option to software only , there might be issue with your graphics error, 2) try to uncheck multicore cpu

Comment: @MustansarSaeed what graphic options do you mean? And where is the multicore checkbox? I'm not on my PC right now

Comment: @Tim: In `Emulator` advanced settings

Comment: @MustansarSaeed nope can't change those options

Comment: @MustansarSaeed I created a different AVD that does allow me to set software graphics, however the same error occurred when I tried to run that one

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It seems a buggy graphic card driver can cause a similar problem. I am not sure if this is generated your problem here or not, but it is worth to say; If you have an NVIDIA graphic card with the driver version of 378.49 (there may be other versions too!), you may experience this error due to some incompatibility with java.
Please update your graphic card driver or rollback it to version an older stable version and try again!. And read [here](https://intellij-support.jetbrains.com/hc/en-us/community/posts/115000060510-Process-finished-with-exit-code-1073740791-0xC0000409-JavaFX-Application) for more information.

Comment: I do have an nvidia card but that faulty driver is 3 years old. I have the latest 441.41 driver. Rolling back to 2017 is not an option

Comment: I am not saying you should roll back to a 2017 version, just try the version 425.31 for instance. Also, I am not sure if only a faulty driver can generate this problem. There may be other sources that can cause this problem.

Answer (score 1):

Here are a few things you can try:

1. Go to AVD manager and open settings for your virtual device. In the Emulated Performance section for graphics, change it from automatic to software.
2. Have a look at [here](https://www.bram.us/2017/05/12/fix-for-the-android-emulator-crashing-during-launch/). There could be an incompatability with other software  incompatibility with other software such as Docker, Oracle Virtual Box and other products that use VCPU.
3. You could try a complete reinstall of Android Studio and make sure all updates are completed. There could be a bug in an older version of the emulator you are using that's fixed in a more recent release.

**Edit**

A couple more things you could try:

1. Open Android Virtual Device Manager, then click on options for virtual device, then wipe data, then cold boot.
2. Go to C:/users/(username)/AppData/Local/Android/Sdk/platform-tools in a terminal, then type adb kill-server, then adb start-server.

**Edit**

You could also try checking for memory leaks https://developer.android.com/studio/profile/memory-profiler and you could try increase the amount of RAM available for the emulator.

Go to Tools->Android->AVD Manager, then edit your AVD, then in the pop-up window click Show Advanced Settings, then finally increase the amount of RAM.

**Edit**

IT could be an issue with libGL or libstdc++. See [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/47739865/2452680)

Comment: 1) the field is not editable for me, set to automatic 2) I don't have any of those 3) it is a fresh install of AS 4.0 with all tools updated

Comment: I tried all the obvious things already. Profiling for app leaks is irrelevant because I'm not even able to run apps

Answer (score 1):

I might have an Idea what your problem is:

Restart the adb Server, you can do so by using the command Prompt in the following way:

First go to C/users/(YOUR USERNAME)/AppData/Local/Android/Sdk/platform-tools with the cd command.
Then just type adb kill-server, and adb start-server, so like this;

```
cd C/users/(YOUR USERNAME)/AppData/Local/Android/Sdk/platform-tools
adb kill-server
adb start-server
```

If that doesent work try to wipe and cold boot described in [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44999569/android-studio-emulator-and-process-finished-with-exit-code-1073741511-0xc000/47707354#47707354) question.

Answer (score 0):

Try this :

Go to Tools ==> SDK Menager ==>Android SDK

(Appearance&Behavior=>System settings=>Android SDK)==>SDK Tools==>Intel x86 Emulator Accelerator(install this).

It will solve your problem.I hope it helps.

Comment: I have an AMD cpu

Answer (score 0):

It sounds like the emulator may have not installed correctly. Check these steps:

1. Ensure that you have installed [Hyper-V](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/virtualization/hyper-v-on-windows/quick-start/enable-hyper-v) . [Documentation for running emulator on AMD](https://www.androidpolice.com/2018/07/09/android-studio-device-emulator-now-works-amd-processors-hyper-v/#:~:targetText=You%20can%20also%20use%20Hyper,HAXM%20will%20stay%20as%20default.&targetText=To%20use%20the%20new%20emulator,through%20the%20Studio%20SDK%20Manager).)
2. Then try this step to force a cold boot:
   [Android Studio Emulator and "Process finished with exit code -1073741511 (0xC0000139)"](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44999569/android-studio-emulator-and-process-finished-with-exit-code-1073741511-0xc000/47707354#47707354)

If Its crashes again, then create a new emulator. You might also try and download a new image just to make sure that the one you installed is not corrupt.

Comment: yes those steps are rather obvious. The error codes are different here btw

Comment: I noticed that too. But considering that your emulator is crashing, and as you did not list steps you have already tried to resolved the issue, one could assume that you have not tried these. You might want to update your question to list the "obvious stuff" you have already tried in order to avoid "obvious" answers!

Answer (score 0):

You said you're using Windows 10? Error code `0xC0000409` is caused by a stack buffer overflow. It seems to have popped up a couple [places](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50562192/process-finished-with-exit-code-1073740791-0xc0000409-pycharm-error) all related by windows systems (might be totally irrespective of the android emulator). If this is the case I found a couple threads that might help solve your problem.

http://www.cplusplus.com/forum/windows/39061/

https://answers.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/forum/all/werfaultexe-the-exception-unknown-software/627da5c0-004a-e011-8dfc-68b599b31bf5?auth=1

http://windowsbulletin.com/solved-exception-code-0xc0000409-error/

https://www.tenforums.com/tutorials/16397-repair-install-windows-10-place-upgrade.html